# mysql --quick option

Tags: mysql, client

When I run mysql with the `--quick option` as suggested in another web posting
`desc <table>` returns a lot of --

whereas when I run mysql without the `--quick` option `desc table` returns normal output.

Table has 7 columns...6 doubles and 1 date col.

Comment: You are welcome :)  (You might want to [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), too...)

Answer (score 3):

> --quick: Do not cache each query result, print each row as it is received

Which means if you `DESCRIBE` a table, and MySQL wants the pretty print (you now, `|`'s between fields, and `-`'s around header & bottom), it does not know yet how long each field in the resultset is going to be, so it assumes the largest width that column may get for the 'boxing'. If you look at `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, you can see for instance `COLUMN_COMMENT` is `varchar(1024)`, all those fields really add up. It may seem you only get `-`'s, but those are just the 'bottom' of the boxing, if you scroll up (assuming your scrollback is big enough), you'll see your desired data is there.

You can:

- use \G as you delimiter for vertical output rather the boxed.
- start the process with automatic vertical output with `--auto-vertical-output`
- start the process with non-tabular / non-boxed output with `mysql --quick -s`